# Как правильно составить SQL запрос в данном случае?

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, socket.io

У меня есть 3 таблицы: **messages** (в ней хранится информация о том, кто отправил сообщение, текст сообщения и дата),  **dialogues** (в ней хранится информация о двух пользователях, которые находятся в диалоге и ID последнего сообщения в этом диалоге), **users** (в ней хранится имя пользователя и остальные данные).
Мне необходимо получить такой результат одним запросом: в таблице **dialogues** я получаю ID получателя сообщения (записываю его в first_user) и получаю ID последнего сообщения в этом диалоге, после этого мне нужно получить имя получателя сообщения по ID из таблицы **users**, после этого мне нужно получить текст сообщения и дату сообщения по ID последнего сообщения из таблицы **messages**.

Тут я получаю ID последнего сообщения в нужном мне диалоге и ID получателя сообщения, которое записывается в first_user

```
SELECT last_message,
   CASE WHEN first_user=1 THEN second_user
        WHEN second_user=1 THEN first_user
        ELSE first_user
   END
FROM dialogues;
```

По итогу у меня должна получится такая таблица/ответ:
username (имя пользователя из таблицы users), content (текст сообщения из таблицы messages), date (дата сообщения из таблицы messages).

Сразу хочу извиниться за то, что я где-то объяснил непонятно. Я сейчас максимально сонный и мозг уже не варит. Всем заранее спасибо!

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос CREATE TABLE всех трёх таблиц - только текстом, а не фотографиями... *должна получится такая таблица/ответ: username (имя пользователя из таблицы users)* Который? их в каждом диалоге - два... да ещё у каждого не по одному диалогу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**messages**

message_id, user_id, text, timestamp

**dialogues**

user_id_1, user_id_2, last_message_id

**users**

user_id, name, lastname, age

```
select 
    d.user_id_2 as first_user,
    d.last_message_id,
    u.name,
    m.text
    m.timestamp
from dialogues as d
left join users as u
on d.user_id_2 = u.user_id
left join messages as m
on d.last_message_id = m.message_id
```

Comment: Если использовать inner join при решении данной задачи, можно потерять записи, для которых нет информации в таблице USER и MESSAGES. 

Использование left join при решении подобных задач безопаснее и является целевым подходом.

Comment: Я понимаю, что заоблачный уровень ваших компетенций не дает вам возможности скрыть надменный сарказм) Теоретические навыки, в которых вы безусловно преуспели, неотемлемая чать профессионализма. Однако есть еще и практика. И вот в условиях практики данные могут приходить из источников, которые, порой, заполнены с огрехами. Именно по этой причине при работе с данными стараются избегать влияния таких "потеряшек". На мой взгляд смысловая нагрузка нашей беседы иссякла.

Comment: Ну нет так нет... а что сервер работает лишнего - какие, право, мелочи.